# can "lemonade" be an adjective?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I found these sayings in the film "Between Two Ferns The Movie 2019"

> Waiter: Can I get you some honey gushers to start?
>
> The customer: What are honey gushers?
>
> Waiter: It's just lemonade.

it seems like "lemonade" here is an adjective. I also heard a lot of Australian people use "lemonade" as an adjective.

But in the dictionary, **lemonade** is a noun

> [lem‧on‧ade](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lemonade) /ˌleməˈneɪd◂/ ●●○ noun [countable, uncountable]
>
> 1 British English a sweet fizzy drink that tastes of lemons
>
> a glass of lemonade
>
> Would you like a lemonade?
>
> 2 a drink made from lemons, sugar, and water

But we have the adjective "**lemony**"

> [lem‧on‧y](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lemony) /ˈleməni/ adjective
>
> smelling or tasting of lemons
>
> a lovely lemony flavour

But it seems like not many people use the adjective "**lemony**". Most would say "**it is lemonade**"

can "**lemonade**" be an adjective?

Comment: It's being used as a noun. What's that drink? It is beer/lemonade/tea/coffee/juice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemonade is being used as a non-count or mass noun, because the enquiry was about the nature or composition of the drink. What is the black stuff in that pile on the ground? It is coal. What is that white powder on your hands (e.g. to a baker)? It is flour. What are honey gushers? It [a honey gusher] is lemonade.

[Mass noun](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/mass_noun.htm)

Comment: Note: 'honey gusher' is also a vulgar term for something else, so there may be a humorous element in the film dialogue.